# Pass JSP variable to a java class method

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a JSP file named as project.jsp. It contains a variable

`String context = request.getcontextpath();`

which will deliver context path of my server URL.

`/ARUBA-LIB-G3245-KITKAT` from `http://localhost:8080/ARUBA-LIB-G3245-KITKAT/`.

Now I want to access this context variable from my `project.jsp` file to java class which is in jar format file and resides in `WEB-INF/lib/AuthenticateDetails.jar`.

How can I access this variable from specified java class file?

Comment: `jsp` is front-end. If you want to process something in the backend you'll have to either use a form-submit or use Ajax.

Comment: This is servlet application. I forget to mention.

Comment: My previous comment still stands. Application, servlet, any backend process.

Comment: Thank you. but there is no option of form submit or ajax. I need to access the variable /project.jsp to /WEB-INF/lib/.java class method. Is it possible without any form interaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as in java, an import statement and so on.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Random"
         import="org.authdetails.dao.SomeClass" %>
```

(Or many imports in one `import=...` with line break in string.

```
<%  new SomeClass(contextPath); %>
```

---

Using the MVC (Model-View-Controller) principle, one normally has a servlet (Controller, compilable!) that prepares the data (Model) and puts the data as request attributes, and then forwards to the JSP (view).

In the JSP you can use EL (Expression Language) variables, where some are [predefined](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/jsp/el-implicit-variables.php) to access session variables, request parameters and such.

Combining that with JSP tags, one rarely needs to use `<% ... %>` scriptlets.

Comment: So you are saying i need to import the class in the jsp file. create an instance of that class set the variable as parameter and access it in class method via that instance.

Comment: Yes. Depends, a static method needs no instance of course, and an instance might be put in the session (no to overdo that).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context path variable to the processing method in the library class (library class should be accessible from the jsp though import directive)

Comment: Can you give any example. It will be helpful.

Comment: @shahadat-hossain :   in your jsp add the following  `<%@ page import="x.y.LibClassName" %>`        and then use it in after to make a method call which takes the contextPath param as: `<% libClassObjectRef.doSomething(contextPath)%>`